# The amount of members of each network {} not comparable

Tags: single-word-requests

I would say the amount of members of each network **are** not comparable. But MicrosoftWord says it is "**is** not comparable"

What is right?

Comment: There is no "right". I would say "are", but I would not use "amount" with a countable set, so I would say "the number of members of each network are not comparable". But there are two separate sources of confusion here, neither of which has a "right" answer. First the tension between the singular formal subject "amount" (or "number") and the plural logical subject "members" - most people would use a plural verb there. Secondly because of the "each", because the comparison is over more than one amount/number. Ignore Word's grammar module, which can't cope with English.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify: "The amount [blah blah] is not comparable"/"the number [blah blah] is not comparable"; in either case, the correct form of the verb is 'is'.